# Formula for the sum of the cube roots and fifth roots of first '$n$' natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anybody know the formula by which these two sums can be computed? At least approximately?

Comment: comparison to the corresponding integrals? Euler-Maclaurin?

Comment: Wolphram alpha gives nothing, so probably only an integral approximation.

Answer (score 1):

These are the [generalized harmonic numbers](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber2/02/) $H_n^{(-\frac{1}{3})}$ and $H_n^{(-\frac{1}{5})}$ and can be computed with the Riemann and Hurwitz zeta functions:
$$H_x^{(r)} = \zeta(r) -\zeta(r,x+1) \qquad r\ne 1$$

Comment: I think I have a much simpler solution for this. But people say what I have derived is trivial.

Comment: @Peaceful "I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain."